# Is there any way we can recover the deleted Dialogflow CX agent?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Hi need help with recovering an agent that was accidentally deleted from the Dialogflow CX Console. Can someone guide with potential steps that can be followed to recover this.

FYI

1. We do not have any backup blob files to restore from
2. We had audit logging & agent backup enabled incase if that can help